# URL Connection close hangs sometimes

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, freeze

I have a function that gets the size of a file on a server. I recognize that closing the connection can take a lot of time, like 10 secs or more, sometimes.
Now I had the situation, that in the Android emulator it hanged forever, but starting the same app on a real device it went through normally.

Can someone explain this behavior or is there a better way to close the connection?

```
public static int getFileSizeFromURL(String sUrl) {
    URL url;
    URLConnection conn;
    int size=0;
    try {
      url = new URL(sUrl);
      conn = url.openConnection();
      size = conn.getContentLength();
      if(size < 0){
      } else {
          conn.getInputStream().close(); <----- hangs here in Simulator.
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be related to your code making a `GET` request when you should really do a `HEAD` request:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
```

I am not sure whether this will fix the problem, but the docs say

> Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance

and a `GET` request will definitely use more resources than a `HEAD` request. Unless a `GET` request is strictly required, you should avoid it. If you are not sure whether the server supports `HEAD` requests, try `HEAD` first and fall back to `GET` if the first attempt fails.

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Answer (score 1):

When size is zero then connection should be disconnect. and when size is more than zero then connection should get input stream working. Try below code.

```
public static int getFileSizeFromURL(String sUrl) {
            URL url;
            URLConnection conn;
            int size=0;
            try {
              url = new URL(sUrl);
              conn = url.openConnection();
              size = conn.getContentLength();
              if(size == 0){
                  conn.disconnect();
              }
              else
                  conn.getInputStream(); <----- hangs here in Simulator.
              }
            catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
            return size;
        }
```

Comment: As far as I know, the class `URLConnection` does not have a `close()` method.

Comment: Rigth it does not have a close. I tried this also in the past.